# getting Use of undefined constant admin - assumed 'admin' in php

Tags: php

I am getting the following error while trying to edit the user

**Notice: Use of undefined constant admin - assumed 'admin' in /include/user_manager.inc.php on line 902**

In line 902 its is like this

```
if ($user_type === admin) {
                    // Agents cannot edit Admin account
                    return $lang['user_manager_permission_denied'];
```

Someone please suggest me why this error

Comment: did you defined the 'admin' , maybe you mean $admin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word should be wrapped inside quotes, else PHP will assume that you are using a constant instead of a literal string

```
if ($user_type === 'admin')
                 --^-----^--
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you meant to use

```
if ($user_type === 'admin') {
```

The way you have it down, admin is a constant which you have not defined, while it should probably be a string.